# viewing the password of a connected SQL Server user

Tags: sql-server, password

Using SSMS, the system had me change the password on the user I was using.
Changed it and thought knew what I was changing it to.
Have done a    Save Password.

So I am able to get in via SSMS, but need to change some scripts that have this user and system doesn't like the password I thought I had entered.

Using the SSMS connection I have, are there any method(s) that would allow me to see what this user's password is?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Change your password, again, to something different and make sure it's saved somewhere safe. That's the easiest way to do this.

Comment: System is not allowing the password to be changed via  Login Properties window.  Sounds like a permissions item.

Comment: If you don't have permissions to change your password, you won't have permissions to do anything else crazy. Passwords aren't stored as their passwords, they are stored as a one way hash. This is your only way.